# Is it possible in C to convert a string in to a simple arithmetic operation?

Tags: c

A project I'm working on has a block of code that goes through data to generate operations and stores them in a string format i.e.

```
 1+58-133+2-315
```

Is it possible to convert a string with just numbers and operators in to a math expression?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: It is possible to write a calculator in C.  There are lots of examples, of different complexities.

Comment: Why store it as a string in the first place? Why not calculate as you go, or at least store it as some kind of tree structure?

Comment: Use Python or another language that supports `eval` :)

Comment: If it is just `+/-`, you can make it trivial by just calling `strtol` and working your way down the string summing the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where your basic data structure skills come into picture. I would let you write your own code, but here are the operations that you need to perform.

**Step 1:** Make a collection of operators and digits. This will help you in identifying them.

**Step 2:** Isolate your numbers and symbols by looking for continous digits.
Also, When you do that,Right a logic for handling negative numbers. Find the negative sign without any operator in left or the ones sorrounded in brackets. 
Store them in a collection (Array or linked list) in the order of their occurance.

**Step 3:** Use your collection and then Convert your Infix expression to Prefix. This helps in eliminating the parenthesis. You can store them in separate collection.

**Step 4:** With this new collection. Use an algorithm to process Prefix expressions.You will have to convert you numeric char* into integars or double as you go and the symbols to their respective "C" equivalent operators.

You are done